# How to convert list from python into comma separated values in python with jinja or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, jinja2

I want to synchronize my dropzone allowfiles templates with my python upload config allowed files. I can get jinja to spit out my UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS with config.UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS but I can not figure out how to format it into a string that can be used in my javascript allowdfiles format. See below for what I get vs what I want.

jinja html template

```
<script>
    let allowed_files = "{{ config.UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS }}";
    console.log(allowed_files)
</script>
```

Console Log

```
[&#39;.jpg&#39;, &#39;.png&#39;, &#39;.gif&#39;]
```

What I want is this string

```
.jpg,.png,.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [safe filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping) like this:

```html
<script>
    let allowed_files = "{{ config.UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS|safe }}";
    console.log(allowed_files)
</script>
```

but it returns a result like this:

```js
[".jpg", ".png", ".gif"]
```

If you want the exact use: `console.log(allowed_files.join())`